# Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial failed test Chapter 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new on Rails. I'm following the tutorial of Michael Hartl, Ruby on Rails Tutorial - Learn Web Development with Rails (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/). I've found an error when I try to pass some tests. My output when I execute *bundle exec rspec* is the next:

```
.........................................F.....

Failures:

  1) Authentication signin with invalid information 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }
       expected css "div.alert.alert-error" with text "Invalid" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.39 seconds
47 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:23 # Authentication signin with invalid information
```

The next files have been more highly changed and I think one of them may be causing the error:

## authentication_pages_rspec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end


describe "signin" do

    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
    end
  end
end
```

## sessions_controler.rb

```
class SessionsController `>` ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:session][:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

## sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user;
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end
end
```

If you need any other file, please let me know and I'll post it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  `<code>...</code>` doesn't work here, so to format code, highlight it and use the `{}` control above the edit box.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Wayne, I was going mad to preserve the format.

Answer (score 2):

I've browsed through your code, and apart from the semicolon in

```
 self.current_user = user;
```

I haven't seen anything strange. You haven't posted the method you're testing,

```
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
```

though, so the problem might be there.

General steps to find the issue:

- restart spark if you're using it.
- test the failing spec manually: does the functionality work?
- if not, fix it
- if the functionality should work, but the spec still fails, use launchy and save_and_open_page to peek at the page during your test.

Addition 1:

well, that part in your spec

```
before { visit signin_path }

describe "with invalid information" do
  before { click_button "Sign in" }
```

leads you to the SessionController create action (because the link links to signin_path which is mapped there in config/routes.rb) and the main logic that could go wrong is `user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])` - which is provided by has_secure_password.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @bento! Hmm... The thing is I'm pretty new using Ruby on Rails and Rspec and I don't know still how to identify the errors on testing. I don't see what is the relation between what Rspec says and what you say about method authenticate.

Apparently, the functionality is working, but according to the tutorial no errors should appear after execute rspec tests...

Comment: As you say @bento, the method *authenticate* is part of *has_secure_password*, so, how could it go wrong? I've followed developing the tutorial and I've obtained a very similar error in other part or rspec tests, and the error is pretty similar: `1) User pages signup with valid information after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
       expected css "div.alert.alert-success" with text "Welcome" to return something
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:39:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'`

Comment: have you tried save_and_open_page? just include the launchy gem and put save_and_open_page before the failing expectation.

Comment: Seriously, now I'm starting to be convinced of the problem is about css and div.alert.alert-error. I'm developing some more tests in Cucumber and the answer is: `expected css "div.alert.alert-error" to return something (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/authentication_steps.rb:10:in '/^he should see an error message$/'
      features/signing_in.feature:6:in 'Then he should see an error message'` I'm going to try that what you say about save_and_open_page. I've never heard anything of that before, but I don't lose anything for try. Thank you a lot =D